# Run external javascript (that "resides" with a span) on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I've been searching around for a while but can't figure it out for my specific case. Using Wordpress/Elementor (though it probably doesn't matter), I would like to run the below code on page load. The script in question is supposed to launch an embedded window and needs the userid parameter. The code originally shows a button, but for my scenario I have removed the class tag,

```
<span class="glf-button" userid="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" > Click here </span>
<script src="https://www.linktoscript.com/script.js" defer async ></script>
```

First I tried to add an ID to the span before trying to "automatically" click on it through js using window.onload / getElementById, which didn't work. I confirmed that I have access to the span by checking innerHTML and getting the "click here" text in the onload function.

I also tried some other posts suggestion about automatically loading and running an external script, which seems to have succeeded in loading the script but the embedded window is never launched. At this point I'm wondering if the fault lies with the script itself.. or maybe SOP preventing it? I probably tried some other wrong things, too, but hey,

**edit:** some suggestions involve getting the span element and autoclicking it, however there seems to be a problem in getting the element through getelementbyid if the script is attached to it (works fine otherwise)..

Many thanks in advance for any and all input!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you want to automatically trigger click on an element on page load.
Are you sure that the external code you are loading does not provide a native way to launch the "embedded window" passing the userId param? That would be the preferred way.

Anyway, I think that your problem may be on "timing".
In your `<script>` you added "defer" and "async", so you defered the code loading, but if you want to launch code when window loaded, you have to load that code as soon as possible. It is possibile that your code triggered the "click" event before external script completed the loading.

Try to remove both "defer" and "async" and ensure that the script is inside `<head></head>`.
Then you can use jQuery to trigger the click:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.('glf-button').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input! I have tried your suggestion and while it may work, it didn't work for my scenario and I think I found out why: using getelementbyid, I cannot get the element (returns as null) if the script is "attached" to the span just right after it, as seen on the code in my post. If I however remove the script I will properly get the element..